# Exclusion Strategy in gson

Tags: java, json, gson

My JSON has the following structure:

```
{"name": [9000, {Inst1}, ..., {Instn}]}
```

Where `9000` is an arbitrary integer and `Insti` are serialized instances of some class.
I'm using something like this for getting all the `Inst` into the list:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Song>>(){}.getType();
```

and trying go exclude that first int by writing something like this:

```
public class ExcludeTotalFound implements ExclusionStrategy {
    private final Class<?> typeToSkip;

    public ExcludeTotalFound(Class<?> typeToSkip) {
        this.typeToSkip = typeToSkip;
    }
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clas_s) {
        return clas_s == typeToSkip;
    }
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fieldAttributes) {
        return typeToSkip.equals(fieldAttributes.getDeclaredClass());
    }
}
```

And, finally, I'm doing

```
gson = new GsonBuilder().addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new ExcludeTotalFound(int.class)).serializeNulls().create();
```

and, then:

```
collection = gson.fromJson(rBody, listType);
```

where rBody is all that raw array, i.e. `{"name": [9000, {Inst1}, ..., {Instn}]`

But all what I get is

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER`
```

What's the problem?

ADD:
As long, as I know that the length of my JSON will never exceed ~500, and that the structure remains always the same, is it good enough to use the following workaround?

```
Iterator<JsonElement> it = rBody.iterator();
it.next();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    collection.add(gson.fromJson(it.next(), Song.class));
}
```

Comment: side note, `Class<?> clas_s` is sometimes written as `Class<?> clazz` - anybody know what is the "standard"

Comment: @SB there is no standard. That's just a parameter name... It helps if you use the same across your application, but if you don't, I don't see a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty similar to this one I answered over here -->
[Gson custom deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730345/gson-custom-deserialization/17730843#17730843). Does that help? It's not by exclusion, but rather by custom deserialization.