# Gson custom deserialization

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using Gson to create and parse JSON, but I've faced one problem. In my code I use this field:

```
@Expose
private ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

But my JSON is formated like this:

```
persons:{count:"n", data:[...]}
```

Data is an array of persons.

Is there any way to convert this JSON into my class using Gson? Can I use a JsonDeserializer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a custom deserializer (http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html), something like:

```
  public static class MyJsonAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<List<Person>>
  {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Person> deserialize( JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context )
      throws JsonParseException
    {
      for (each element in the json data array) 
      {
        Person p = context.deserialize(jsonElementFromArray,Person.class );
        people.add(p);
      }
    }
    return people;
  }
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but there is still occure "IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT". Here is my implementation: http://pastebin.com/4ZYs0S9A

Comment: It was basically pseudo code, not something you can drop in. You'd have to get the correct element corresponding to the data, then parse that. See the deserialize method here (starting like 1089), it's a complicated deserializer I wrote once upon a time: https://github.com/chriskessel/MyHex/blob/master/src/kessel/hex/domain/Player.java

Comment: Thanks for reply! I just couldn't deal with serializers, but now, seems like, I finally get it

Answer (score 5):

You can try below code to parse your json

```
String jsonInputStr = "{count:"n", data:[...]}";

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson(jsonInputStr, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();
List<Person> persons = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get("data").toString(), new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: actually I did it this way